# How to block the website by IP address in Javascript

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have developed web site using reactjs and node js. I need to allow only particular IPs. i need to block rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to correctly block IP adresses in Node.JS server app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63455999/how-to-correctly-block-ip-adresses-in-node-js-server-app)

Comment: Important points: 1) IP blocking is almost ineffective because it can be easily changed. 2) The preferable solution would be to block an IP address at a lower level – before it gets to Node.JS.

Comment: why not using private vpn? you can look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218213/how-do-you-connect-to-vpn-using-node-js